# How to translate custom post type content in Wordpress 3?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, multilingual

I am using WPML in a Wordpress site, and just noticed that I cannot translate my custom post types.

Does anybody know a workaround, or an alternative to WPML, that will let me do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the latest version of WPML you need to install the 'Translation management' add-on and on its admin page you have to specifically activate WPML for your custom post type.

hope this helps